# C How to avoid Seg Fault when Searching a String Array With strcmp?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp

I am a beginner, and I can't figure out why I'm getting a seg fault here

```
/* Program runs based on user input. Once the program reaches here, the values are.. */
/* students = { 11111 }; */
/* course_count = 1; */
/* courses = { "abc1234" }; */

char **courses;
char * requestedCourse;

/* Other stuff happens here */

do {
    printf("Enter a course code: ");
    scanf("%s", requestedCourse);
    while (getchar() != '\n')
          ;
    for (i = 0; i < course_count; i++){
    courseExists = courseInArray(courses, course_count, requestedCourse);
    if (courseExists == 1){
      valid = 1;
      break;
    }
    }
    if (valid == 0){
      puts("Course not found. Try again.");
      while (getchar() != '\n')
          ;
    }


} while (valid == 0);


}

int courseInArray(char **arr, int len, char *target) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
/* Segmentation fault happens here, I believe */
    if(strcmp(arr[i], target) == 0) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Register a student:
Enter a student number: 11111
Enter a course code: abc1234
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

All I'm trying to do is search two arrays to ensure the values exist. This is driving me crazy. I am trying to understand segmentation faults but I have not been able to wrap my head around it yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is only a snippet of my code, so if the answer isn't entirely clear I can post more. Thank you.

Comment: Please learn how to create https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- you'll get better answers that way.

Answer (score 1):

This declares a local variable, which points to... nowhere in particular.

> `char * requestedCourse;`

This:

```
  scanf("%s", requestedCourse);
```

attempts to copy a string into the memory pointed at by the `requestedCourse`. Since you don't know what `requestedCourse` points at, this is undefined behavior and is most likely the root cause of the crash.

I suggest reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).